# Applying border properties to a UIButton crashes on ipad not on simulator ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, uikit, calayer

I am applying following layer properties on a button (IBOutlet)

```
CGColorRef colorRef = [[UIColor colorWithRed:180.0f/255.0f green:243.0f/255.0f blue:254.0f/255.0f alpha:1] CGColor];
button.layer.borderWidth = 4;
button.layer.borderColor = colorRef;
button.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;
```

I have added QuartzCore Library and have imported QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h in my .m file too.

This code works fine on 6.1 Simulator, but crashes on both ipad 3 with iOS 6.0.1 and ipad with iOS 5.1.1 with no infomatory error. Stack trace does not show anything useful.

FYI i am also applying some other properties on CALayer and they are working fine on all devices.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I got the reason of the crash. I was applying same color ref to three buttonn and it did not allow me.

Comment: I want to know why was it crashing when i use same color ref for three buttons.  CGColorRef colorRef = [[UIColor colorWithRed:180.0f/255.0f green:243.0f/255.0f blue:254.0f/255.0f alpha:1] CGColor]; button1.layer.borderColor = colorRef; button2.layer.borderColor = colorRef; button3.layer.borderColor = colorRef;

Comment: @madLokesh any comments on this please.

Comment: Please post the crash log @user746344

Comment: have you imported quartzcore framework